# Avoid duplicated key error when saving entity

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm starting with Play! Framework 2 and I'm facing an issue when trying to save an entity to the database (Postgres).

I've created a Model where there is a `@Column(unique = true)` annotation on `name` attribute. So, there must be two unique attributes when saving: the ID, which is always correctly generated and the name, which is an input provided by the user.

When I check for errors in Controller (`filledForm.hasErrors()`), there are no errors, because (I guess) it does not check for duplicated attributes, but just for form errors.

Then it goes to the Model and tries to save the object `thebean.save();`. And then it "crashes" and shows an error in the browser.

My question is: since the `save()` method returns void, how can I catch this error and know what kind of error it is (to warn the user)?

Thanks

Comment: How does it 'crash'? Does it throw an exception? What is the error message?

Comment: Actually, crash it was just a way to say. When debugging, I could see that it throws a PersistenceException. I know I can control this creating a method and checking the parameter `name` manually in the controller, but I'm wondering if the framework already has a method to check this automatically, just like `hasErrors()` does in as form.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to just use a try {} catch {} to catch the PersistenceException?

Comment: I could do this, but, apparently, I would not know the attribute that failed. Only if I make some kind of filter in the string message that the exception throws, which I think it's not a good way to do it.

Comment: I still have trouble to understand. You write you check with `filledForm.hasErrors()`, but with this you just call the `validate()` function of your entity class and if you want to check something you could just implement it there, right?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution is to manualy check constraint.
There is a entity method called validate() (in models). It's automatically called when form is validating.
So:

```
public List<ValidationError> validate() {
    List<ValidationError> errors = new ArrayList<>();

    if(YouModel.find.where().eq("name", name).ne("entity_id", entity_id).findRowCount() != 0){
        errors.add(new ValidationError("name", "error.yourModel.name.unique"));
        return errors;
    }

    return null;
}
```

`error.yourModel.name.unique` is a custom constant from /conf/messages file. You should create it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had to switch to another project this week. But I'll check this as soon as possible and post a feedback. Thank you for now!